# Matching words starting with a hash(#) sign

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract words from a line which starts with a hash(#) symbol.

Suppose the line is :

> #This #is#the line #containing multiple #tags.

The regex which I am using is :

```
(?:^|\s)(#\w+)
```

The answer which I'm getting is :

> #This , #is , #containing , #tags

The output should be

> #This , #is#the , #containing , #tags.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is it because of '/s' since only the words having a space before them are getting picked.

Comment: Why not just `#[a-z]+`? Of course, replace `[a-z]` with whatever can be in a tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#` is a non-word character.  As such, the output that you get is expected.

Instead of looking for word characters match anything that is not a space.

```
(?:^|\s)(#[^ ]+)
```